# Installing Rancher using docker containers is taking too long and is getting connection timeout

Tags: kubernetes, rancher

I am trying to install a K8S cluster with Rancher, after installing docker successfully I ran the following command to install Rancher containers:

```
$ sudo docker run -d --restart=unless-stopped -p 8088:8088 rancher/server:stable
```

The console I got was:
[image]

As you can see I am not being able to download the Rancher containers, what could I do to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

Well, starting with the point this Rancher installation is based on what is proposed in this link https://phoenixnap.com/kb/install-rancher-on-ubuntu. The Rancher version to be installed following the script in the link, according to Docker Hub, is 1.x.

So, I don't recommend the command proposed in the script:

```
sudo docker run -d --restart=unless-stopped -p 8080:8080 rancher/server:stable
```

See, the rancher/server must be replaced by: rancher/rancher:stable, then you will install latest Rancher version 2.x.
Also, to avoid the timeout problem you instead of using the command "docker run" go for "docker pull" first, then "docker run". In other words, after finishing the "pull" then you go with the "run" option. I recommend you run the following commands which will be faster and effective:

```
sudo docker pull rancher/rancher:latest

sudo docker run -d --restart=unless-stopped -p 8088:8088 -p 8443:8443 --privileged rancher/rancher:latest
```

After running that everything is in good shape, you can run your Rancher. I hope that can help someone, I lost one day to figure that out, since the download time takes hours each time you run to timeout and fail.